# Saving data to sequence file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, hadoop2

I'm trying to do some sort of filtering on Sequence file, and save it back to another sequence file, example:

```
val subset = ???
val hc = sc.hadoopConfiguration

val serializers = List(
  classOf[WritableSerialization].getName,
  classOf[ResultSerialization].getName
).mkString(",")

hc.set("io.serializations", serializers)

subset.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
  "output/sequence",
  classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable],
  classOf[Result],
  classOf[SequenceFileOutputFormat[ImmutableBytesWritable, Result]],
  hc
)
```

After compilation I receive following error:

```
Class[org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable,org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result]](classOf[org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat]) 

required: Class[_ <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.OutputFormat[_, _]] classOf[SequenceFileOutputFormat[ImmutableBytesWritable, Result]],
```

To my knowledge SequenceFileOuputFormat extends FileOutputFormat which extends OutputFormat, but I am missing something.

Can you please help?

I raised issue with Spark team at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25405

Comment: please share full stack trace

Comment: there is one more line saying Error: type mismatch